# AWS Lambda Node JS 8.10 Syntax error in handler function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have below AWS lambda method

NodeJS 8.10.0

```
// 'use strict';
var fs = require("fs");

class ReadFile{
    constructor(file){
        if(undefined == file){
          this.file = "./index.html";
        }
    }

    content(){
        var buff = fs.readFileSync(this.file);
        return Buffer.from(buff, 'base64').toString('ascii');
    }

}
exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
    var f = new ReadFile(event.file);
    callback(null, f.content());
    // callback(null,f.content());
};
```

I got Syntax error

But Same method is working when I define it in handlers without class like below

```
exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
    if (undefined === event.file) {
        event.file = "index.html";
    }
    var cn = fs.readFileSync(event.file);
    callback(null, Buffer.from(cn, 'base64').toString('ascii'));
    // callback(null,f.content());
};
```

Got error

```
{errorMessage=RequestId: a51e4f417 Process exited before completing request}
```

Comment: Could you provide more information about where you got 'syntax error'. I tried your code and did not get any error at all. My node is 8.9.4

Comment: {errorMessage=RequestId: f3d0a51e4f417 Process exited before completing request}

Comment: In lambda it is showing success but while open index.html in google chrome I got the error

Comment: Looks like you trying to read nonexistent file and your process failed with exception. Then you receive this error message

Comment: @Vasyl File is exists thats why the below code was running well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like problem was in your constructor code. I think that your missing `else` part of condition. So try to replace

```
    constructor(file){
       if(undefined == file){
         this.file = "./index.html";
       }
    }
```

to

```
    constructor(file){
       if(undefined == file){
         this.file = "./index.html";
       }
       else {
         this.file = file;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because your function finish before than your callback ends its execution. You'll need to put the callback in a **setTimeOut** to finish its execution. This happens because nodeJS uses blocking execution and the callback doesn't return something.

Try with the following structure:

```js
exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
    if (undefined === event.file) {
        event.file = "index.html";
    }
    var cn = fs.readFileSync(event.file);
    
    setTimeout(() => { //Timeout to execute the callback
    
      callback(null, Buffer.from(cn, 'base64').toString('ascii'));
      // callback(null,f.content());
    
    }, 10000);
    
    
};
```

As you can see, I added callback in a timeout to load it. This method become the code to Non-blocking and your main function won't finish without its callback.

If you want to use the first structure, just put all your code in main handler and your callback in a timeout like the example.